# Relock bootloader - "FAILED (remote: unknown command)"

Tags: fastboot, sony-xperia, bootloader-lock

I'm getting rid of my Sony XZ2 Compact. I just flashed the original firmware using Emma and now I'm trying to relock the bootloader.

I've tried running `fastboot oem lock` and `fastboot flashing lock` both as a normal user and root with no avail. I always get the following error:

```
>> fastboot oem lock                      
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

When I run `fastboot devices` I can see my phone listed. USB-Debugging is active in the developer options.

How can I lock the bootloader so that I don't get the screen with "*Your device software can't be checked for corruption. Please lock the bootloader.*" when booting the phone?